# T-SQL Pivot with multiple aggregates on the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This seems like it should be a common need, but I'm not seeing how to do this using T-SQL PIVOT function.  Specifically, I want to calculate the AVG and STDEV for a column over a Pivot column value.  The data look something like this (lots of data omitted, but this gets to the heart):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID           Year     PersonID     Score 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
106          2001        1          20
107          2002        1          30       
108          2003        1          40       
109          2004        1          50     
106          2002        2          20
107          2003        2          50       
108          2004        2          30       
109          2005        2          10   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to see the following output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
NonPivotCol1 NonPivotCol2  2001_Mean   2001_Avg  2002_Mean  2002_Avg  Etc 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Some Value   Some Value       32          5.2       28          3.1 
Etc. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do I need to revert to the old CASE statement logic?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT - Multiple Aggregates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243567/sql-server-pivot-multiple-aggregates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Just use the old style `CASE` syntax.

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Year = 2001 THEN Score END) AS 2001_Avg,
       STDEV(CASE WHEN Year = 2001 THEN Score END) AS 2001_StDev /*...*/
```

`PIVOT` is just (less versatile) syntactic sugar for this anyway.

[Oracle supports multiple aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987067/pivoting-of-data-using-two-columns/11988486#11988486) in `PIVOT` but TSQL doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

use case statements. You have to specify all columns anyway and I'd say that case is more usable than pivot

```
select
  avg(case when [Year] = 2001 then [Score] else null end) as [2001_Avg],
  avg(case when [Year] = 2002 then [Score] else null end) as [2002_Avg]
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two PIVOTs and join them

```
WITH MinPivot AS
(
  SELECT 
         [2001] AS [2001_MEAN], 
         [2002] AS [2002_MEAN], 
         [2003] AS [2003_MEAN], 
         [2004] AS [2004_MEAN], 
         [2005] AS [2005_MEAN]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Year,Score
    FROM Table1
  ) As S
  PIVOT
  (
     STDEV(Score)
     FOR Year in([2001],[2002],[2003],[2004],[2005])
  )
  AS pvt
),
AvgPivot AS
(
  SELECT 
         [2001] AS [2001_AVG],
         [2002] AS [2002_AVG],
         [2003] AS [2003_AVG], 
         [2004] AS [2004_AVG], 
         [2005] AS [2005_AVG] 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Year,Score
    FROM Table1
  ) As S
  PIVOT
  (
     AVG(Score)
     FOR Year in([2001],[2002],[2003],[2004],[2005])
  )
  AS pvt
)

SELECT *
FROM MinPivot M
CROSS JOIN AvgPivot A
```

Have a look at [this fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/054e4/2)

Comment: This is much less efficient than just using `CASE` as you perform the grouping and aggregation twice (as well as adding an additional join in)

Comment: It is an alternative in any case.