# How can I know GROUP BY is missing data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a process that reads tons of files and imports all that data into our sql server table. Due to the complexity of these tasks, I can only work with the data after it's been inserted to our tsql table.

The name of this table is [CounterRawData15mins] and data looks like this:

```
Cell   Date      Hour    Minute    Counter   Value
AB1    20141008  14      00        C1        10
AB1    20141008  14      15        C1        20
AB1    20141008  14      30        C1        30
AB1    20141008  14      45        C1        40
CF4    20141008  14      00        C1        50
CF4    20141008  14      15        C1        40
CF4    20141008  14      45        C1        20
```

We have several reports that use this data at hourly intervals, simply by grouping by cell and minute. If I want to see the total for counter **C1** by hour, I could use this query:

```
SELECT Cell, Date, Hour, sum(C1) FROM CounterRawData15mins 
PIVOT (SUM(value) FOR counter in (C1) ) AS pvt 
where Date = 20141008
GROUP BY Cell, Date, Hour
```

With the data above, the query will add everything correctly. Unfortunately, if you notice, cell **CF4** doesn't have data for hour 14:30, so the total here for **CF4** of 120 is incorrect since there there's data missing. **AB1** has data for 14:00 - 14:45, so that's correct.

Since most of the queries are similar to the one above, is it possible to, perhaps, add some identifier that will mark a record as not having all the data of its 4 quarters?

For example, running the query above, the desired result would be:

```
Cell   Date      Hour    C1     DataMissing
AB1    20141008  14      100    
CF4    20141008  14      110    Yes
```

And if there's a way to determine (through the same query) what data 15-min quarter is missing, even better.

I also have a [Time] table with all the possible combinations of hours and 15-minute periods, but I'm not sure how to do the outer join.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to have a table with all of the hour/minute combinations you want to display, and do an outer join from that table to your `CounterRawData15mins` table.

Comment: Besides that, using a `GROUP BY` statement could do the trick. About DataMissing, you could check that if each Cell counts less than 4, it means there's some quarter missing. Not that complicate, and useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, data missing means that you have a row missing. In that case, you could use `COUNT(*)` with a case statement to solve your problem:

```
SELECT Cell, 
       Date, 
       Hour, 
       SUM(C1) as C1, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 4 
         THEN '' 
         ELSE 'Yes' 
       END as DataMissing
  FROM CounterRawData15mins
 PIVOT (SUM(value) FOR counter in (C1) ) AS pvt 
 WHERE Date = 20141008
 GROUP BY Cell, Date, Hour
```

The above query assumes the 15 minute intervals that you're listing, but you could set the check to be whatever the appropriate expected numbers of minutes are. You could do different checks based on your count amount.

EDIT: Based on your comment, I took a different approach. Really what you're wanting to do is pivot multiple aggregates, which gets messy. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243567/sql-server-pivot-multiple-aggregates) as a reference, this produced the results I was looking for:

```
select 
    Cell, 
    Date, 
    Hour,
    C1 = SUM(CASE WHEN counter = 'C1' THEN value else 0 end),
    C2 = SUM(CASE WHEN counter = 'C2' THEN value else 0 end),
--Each column needed
C1DataIssue = 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN counter = 'C1' THEN minute else NULL end) = 4 THEN '' 
    ELSE 'Yes' END,
C2DataIssue = 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN counter = 'C2' THEN minute else NULL end) = 4 THEN '' 
    ELSE 'Yes' END
from dbo.CounterRawData15mins
group by cell, date, hour
```

You still have the problem (that's just as true for a pivot) that you have to build out for each column, but this winds up being a lot less messy than juggling multiple pivots.

EDIT2: Here's a SQL Fiddle [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33250/2) where I set up two bad data cases, with cell AB1 and counter C2, there are two 15 minute increments, and in cell CF4 and counter C1 is your original example

Comment: I added the count to my query, but it displays an odd number, not anything between 1 and 4.

Comment: The problem is that your query works if each cell only has one counter (C1). Unfortunately, Each cell has several counters (C1, C2, C3, etc), but for this total I'm only using **C1**. Your query counts all the counters for the cell.

Comment: @vmgmail Good point. I added an alternate way to get to the same result. Let me know how that does for you.

Comment: I just noticed that the problem isn't with the amount of counters, it's that my table has an IDENTITY key. For some reason, the IDENTITY key screws up the count.

Comment: @vmgmail Unless there's some extra code that you haven't posted, a key column, regardless of if it's identity or not, shouldn't affect your grouping.

Comment: What fixed the problem was using `COUNT(C1)` instead of `count(*)`.